# How did Brother Kwame's words almost make that 'whole pig' (white cops) nightmare worthwhile?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, blackkklansman

In *BlacKkKlansman* (2018), both eating, Patrice speaks to Ron Stallworth:

> Patrice: When we dropped Brother Kwame off at the airport, he told me
>   that the Black Power movement needed strong sisters like me to lead
>   the fight against capitalist oppression and the politicians and pigs
>   who perpetuate it. **His words almost made that whole pig nightmare
>   worthwhile**.

How did Brother Kwame's words almost make that 'whole pig' (white cops) nightmare worthwhile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that Brother Kwame's words were so inspiring that it almost made it worthwhile going against the cops (the white pig nightmare mentioned).

Obviously people generally don't *want* to fight cops for no good reason, so his words were almost a good enough reason to fight.